# In The Blue Cross, what is the mailbag trick?

Tags: short-stories, g-k-chesterton, father-brown

From the Father Brown story ["The Blue Cross"](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/204/204-h/204-h.htm#link2H_4_0001):

> It was he who had kept up an unaccountable and close correspondence with a young lady whose whole letter-bag was intercepted, by the extraordinary trick of photographing his messages infinitesimally small upon the slides of a microscope.

What is the "trick" being described here? I don't understand what it is or how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He made very, very, very small letters, on microscope slides.  These were sent to the young lady in question, who used a microscope to read them.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't get that the recipient of the micro-messages was the young lady (I thought that the unaccountability was paart of the trick, not the result.)

Answer (score 1):

"The Blue Cross" was the first Father Brown story, published (according to Wikipedia) in 1910.

The technology of [photo microdots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdot?wprov=sfla1) had been known for some decades by then.

Comment: Could you explain what photo microdots are, and how they relate to the story? We prefer answers to be self-contained.